# Site served with Nginx, and hosted at DigitalOcean, is down

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost, offline

My site suddenly went down: 198.199.100.120 - Ubuntu 10.12 x32 Server at DigitalOcean.

The log is http://pastie.org/private/4dzzm5rwvh17l8whrlbpqa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a permission problem on your filesystem. If this happened out of nowhere my guess is that your quota is full. Try `df -h` and check if there is space left on your partitions. If there is no problem, check the permissions of your nginx error / access log files (at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and `/var/log/nginx/access.log`) plus the avatar directory and files of your WordPress installation (at `/var/www/wp-content/uploads/avatars`).